# Will high voltage but low current glow a bulb?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, electronics

Suppose I increase the voltage supplied to a building from a constant power source substantially by putting a transformer. Doing this would reduce the current substantially as well. So will the building's electronics still work?

Comment: You've gone from a bulb in the title to an entire building in the detail. But that aside, did you really mean a *constant **power** source* because if so then I have an answer that's very different to the ones already there (not got time to write it just yet though). If you meant the power supply was a constant **voltage** source (with negligible source impedance) then see Elio's answer.

Answer (score 1):

$\def\Ip{I_{\rm pr}} \def\Is{I_{\rm sec}}$
You're doing a very common mistake. It's totally false that to

> increase the voltage supplied to a building from a constant power
>   source substantially by putting a transformer[...] would reduce the
>   current substantially

The effect would be to burn every electrical equipment connected to
that building's mains.

You're not alone in holding the false belief that if a transformer
increases voltage than it decreases current. Things are rather
different. It's true that in an upward transformer

$V$(secondary) $>$ $V$(primary) and $I$(secondary) $<$ $I$(primary).

But if voltages are given, currents are determined by load.

Assume a simple load, a resistor $R$. If you connect it to primary
source $V_1$ the current will be $I=V_1/R$. Now install your
transformer, say with an upward ratio $V_2/V_1=k>1$. If $R$ is
connected to secondary, current will become 
$$\Is = V_2/R = k\,V_1/R = k\,I.$$
It will increase, not decrease!

As to primary current you'll have
$$\Ip = k\,\Is = k^2 I.$$
Let's compute the dissipated power $W=I^2 R$.

- without transformer $W = V_1^2 / R$
- with transformer $W = V_2^2 / R = k^2 V_1^2 / R.$

If $k$ is substantially greater than 1 (say 1.2) the power will
increase by a factor $k^2 = 1.44$. Very few appliances - if any - would withstand the test.

Answer (score 0):

There are some pieces of electronics that need an alternated current to work, so they would not work anymore with a constant voltage. The electronics that uses a transformer already will work if you can connect it without its transformer and if you can provide the exact voltage they need.